# Static Random Number in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using the following formula in an attempt to create a static random number.

```
Random Number: Format(Int((99999999-11111111+1)*Rnd([Numbers]+11111111)))
```

Yet, it returns a different non-static random number.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could negate the numerical argument supplied to the [`Rnd`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rnd-function-503cd2e4-3949-413f-980a-ed8fb35c1d80) function to cause the [`Rnd`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rnd-function-503cd2e4-3949-413f-980a-ed8fb35c1d80) function to return the same random number for the given seed value (that is, there would be a one-to-one mapping between the random numbers and the seed values):

> **Syntax**
>
> `Rnd[(number)]`
>
> **Return Values**
>
> If *number* is
>
> - **Less than zero: The same number every time, using number as the seed.**
> - Greater than zero: The next random number in the sequence.
> - Equal to zero: The most recently generated number.
> - Not supplied: The next random number in the sequence.

```
?rnd(-2)
 0.7133257 
?rnd(-2)
 0.7133257 
?rnd(-3)
 0.9633257 
?rnd(-3)
 0.9633257
```

However, a better approach might be to either populate an additional field in your source table with the static random number, or construct a separate table containing the mapping between names & random numbers.

For your particular case, since you are looking to generate 8-digit random numbers, you would use:

```
10000000 + Int(90000000 * Rnd(-[Names]))
```

This will yield a random number in the range `10000000` to `99999999`.

Comment: *"I tried the Rnd[(number)] as you suggested, and it does not work."* What code did you use and what error did you receive?

Comment: As suggested, you should negate the numerical argument you are supplying to the `Rnd` function to cause the same random number to be returned for the given seed. Hence your code would become something along the lines of: `Rnd(-[Names])` (assuming that `[Names]` is numerical data).

Comment: @RebaCat This is because `-[Names]+11111111` will likely yield a positive number (depending on how large/small your `Names` field is), and so you are no longer passing a negative number to the `Rnd` function. I have updated my answer above to help you.

Comment: You're most welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and also upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function RandomRowNumber from my article:

[Random Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33030/Random-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

```
' Builds random row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
'
' 2018-09-11. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RandomRowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional Reset As Boolean) _
    As Single

    ' Error codes.
    ' This key is already associated with an element of this collection.
    Const KeyIsInUse        As Long = 457

    Static Keys             As New Collection

    On Error GoTo Err_RandomRowNumber

    If Reset = True Then
        Set Keys = Nothing
    Else
        Keys.Add Rnd(-Timer * Keys.Count), Key
    End If

    RandomRowNumber = Keys(Key)

Exit_RandomRowNumber:
    Exit Function

Err_RandomRowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case KeyIsInUse
            ' Key is present.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error.
            Resume Exit_RandomRowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```

A demo is included for download.

Code may also be found on **GitHub**: [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers)