# How do I fix random numbers after they've been generated in access?

Tags: ms-access

I have generated unique pseudorandom numbers for each row which are subject to a particular field (Field1) in a query in Access. They have been successfully generated and I would like to fix them (kind of like copy and pasting as values). I guess my question would be, is this the best way to do this or will they always change as they are being recalculated on the query? I am open to any other suggestions, but once they have been calculated for the first time, I want them to stay as they are and not change again. Thanks!

Here is the current query's SQL:

```
SELECT [qry_1].*, Rnd([Field1]) AS Random
FROM qry_1;
```

Comment: Save to a 'temp' table. Table is permanent but records are temporary. Run INSERT action with the SELECT query as source. Since we don't know what you are really trying to accomplish, can't say if this is 'best' way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static Random Number in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909397/static-random-number-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a table. You can use a collection:

```
' Builds random row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
'
' Usage (typical select query with random ordering):
'   SELECT RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RandomRowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RandomRowNumber("",True))
'   ORDER BY RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID]));
'
' The Where statement shuffles the sequence when the query is run.
'
' Usage (typical select query for a form with random ordering):
'   SELECT RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RandomRowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   ORDER BY RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID]));
'
' The RandomRowID values will resist reordering and refiltering of the form.
' The sequence can be shuffled at will from, for example, a button click:
'
'   Private Sub ResetRandomButton_Click()
'       RandomRowNumber vbNullString, True
'       Me.Requery
'   End Sub
'
' and erased each time the form is closed:
'
'   Private Sub Form_Close()
'       RandomRowNumber vbNullString, True
'   End Sub
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset random counter manually:
'   Call RandomRowNumber(vbNullString, True)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RandomRowID] )
'   SELECT RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RandomRowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RandomRowID] )
'   SELECT RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RandomRowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RandomRowNumber("",True)=0);
'
' 2018-09-11. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RandomRowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional Reset As Boolean) _
    As Single

    ' Error codes.
    ' This key is already associated with an element of this collection.
    Const KeyIsInUse        As Long = 457

    Static Keys             As New Collection

    On Error GoTo Err_RandomRowNumber

    If Reset = True Then
        Set Keys = Nothing
    Else
        Keys.Add Rnd(-Timer * Keys.Count), Key
    End If

    RandomRowNumber = Keys(Key)

Exit_RandomRowNumber:
    Exit Function

Err_RandomRowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case KeyIsInUse
            ' Key is present.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error.
            Resume Exit_RandomRowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```

It is explained in detail in my article [Random Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33030/Random-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

(If you have no account, browse to the link: Read the full article).

Full code including a demo is on GitHub: [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers)

Comment: Amazing Gustav, I really appreciate the insight.